# Adding tapjoy banner ads- android

Tags: android, android-layout, tapjoy

I have activity (second activity) , where at the bottom I want to put banner ads(350x50). I have a linearLayout(adLinear) at the bottom of my view and I want ads to come out here. Unfortunately, in tapjoys knowledge center , there are 0 information about adding ads through xml..

So, I read knowledge center of TapJoy few times and everything that I got and did is follow:

```
//imported classes
import com.tapjoy.TapjoyConnect;
import com.tapjoy.TapjoyDisplayAdNotifier;
```

At onCreate added

```
TapjoyConnect.requestTapjoyConnect(context, "myID", "mySecret");
```

And here I stucked. According to KC I have to implemet

```
getDisplayAdResponse(View view);
```

I read knowledge center , looked at the demo code, but I didnt get, how do I need to show banner ads exactly on the place where I want it? Do I need to update linearLayout or add it dynamically? Any helps from people who has done this, would be much appreciated.